# Org-mode header properties from .authinfo.gpg?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, authinfo

I was just looking at [This literate SQL / org-mode example](http://howardism.org/Technical/Emacs/literate-database.html) and see that org-mode supports username and password fields in a SQL source code block. As illustrated there:

```
** MySQL Analysis
  :PROPERTIES:
  :engine:   mysql
  :dbhost:   localhost
  :database: <redacted>
  :dbuser:   <redacted>
  :dbpassword: <redacted>
  :cmdline:  --protocol=tcp
  :exports:  both
  :END:
```

As fun as storing credentials in plain text is, I'm hoping someone can suggest a straightforward path to pulling those critical bits from a gpg-encrypted .authinfo.gpg file.

What's the best way of pulling those properties from .authinfo.gpg, emacs gurus?

Comment: Maybe you can save the entire file with `gpg`. something like `mysqlstuff.org.gpg`

Comment: That would technically work, though it would thwart being able to share the org file as documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a suitable lisp-function which returns the suitable string.

E.g. if you already had function `my-secret-password' which picks the password for a user, you could write

```
** MySQL Analysis
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:   :engine:   mysql
:header-args:   :dbhost:   localhost
:header-args:   :database: MY_DB
:header-args:   :dbuser:   DB_GUY
:header-args:   :dbpassword: (my-secret-password "DB_GUY@MY_DB" )
:header-args:   :cmdline:  --protocol=tcp
:header-args:   :exports:  both
:END:
```

Also note the syntax of the properties for the recent Org version.

It remains to write the suitable function (to replace the `my-secret-password' from above.)

I think this function could build on `auth-source-search' (and needs some energy to get into existence.)

```
Invested some energy (20161117):
```

After a little research I found a concrete example how to pull out a password from the return of `auth-source-search'.

With my personal settings I get my password for marco.wahl@gmail.com with the lisp line

```
(funcall (plist-get (car (auth-source-search :user  "marco.wahl@gmail.com")) :secret ))
```

You need to find such line for your 'dbpassword' and insert it at the right place at the properties.  Possibly it is

```
:PROPERTIES:
...
:header-args:   :dbpassword: (funcall (plist-get (car (auth-source-search :user  "Peter@my-super-db")) :secret ))
...
:END:
```

Comment: I would need to wrap that in a src_emacs-lisp{} block?

Comment: No, this is independent of src_emacs-lisp{} block.  Maybe you can do that.

Comment: I added more details to the answer.

Comment: Don't you need header-args+, instead?

Comment: If I understand correctly the "+" applies when using the same property on multiple lines.  See http://orgmode.org/Changes.html, search for 'header-args:'.

Comment: I think the second colon of the argument keyword is too much.  E.g. :engine: should be :engine.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Marco Wahl and [this emacs documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/auth/Help-for-developers.html) I came up with the following emacs-lisp to put in the PROPERTIES drawer:

```
:PROPERTIES:
...
:header-args: :dbpassword: (funcall (plist-get (nth 0 (auth-source-search :user "Peter" :port 3306 :require '(:secret))) :secret))
...
:END:
```

The :port is not needed but I figured it would help narrow down the search for just MySQL DBs. The :require makes sure that the entry has a passphrase. I personally used this at the head of the file as `#+PROPERTY: header-args :dbpassword elisp-func` but the function should work just as well in the PROPERTIES drawer.

I did try Marco Wahl's answer and it didn't work for me, unfortunately. My solution is very close to his though so I'm sure we looked through similar documentation.